# Translating into participle adjectives

Tags: traducción, participio

Cómo se traducir las oraciones de ingles que tienen verbos que son usado como un adjectivo.

Poe ejemplo:

> Do not touch a smiling cow

O

> The Spanish speaking population is increasing in the United States

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones.

La tradicional, pero hoy rara con algunos verbos, es usar el antiguo participio activo, formado con el sufijo *-ante* o *-(i)ente* (sobre la misma raíz que tiene el participio presente). No es siempre predecible si lleva *-i-* o no. En tus ejemplos, esta forma suena más natural:

> una vaca sonriente
>   la población hispanohablante

La otra, más frecuente en el español moderno si no hay un adjetivo frecuentemente usado, es usar una cláusula subordinada con *que*:

> una vaca que sonríe
>   la población que habla español

Comment: Lo segundo vendría siendo una cláusula relativa reducida, lo que ellos básicamente usan en inglés, pero al primer ejemplo no aplicaría, sería algo del estilo *no toques a una vaca que sonríe = do not touch a cow smiling at me.*

Comment: Would anyone like to expand on why it is not a subjunctive - the sort of cow who smiles - as opposed to - a cow who is smiling right now? I think it is technically called a generic relative in English.

Comment: @mdewey: The subjunctive (*No toques a una vaca que sonría*) also works. Actually, both convey virtually identical meanings in this case: 1. No toques a la vaca que sonríe: there's a specific cow smiling; 2. No toques a una vaca que sonríe: There could be a cow smiling or not, or it could refer to a general concept; 3. No toques a una vaca que sonría: same as (2); 4. No toques a la vaca que sonría: same as (2). (2) might make it sound slighty more likely that a cow is actually smiling than (3) does. (4) is generally used when only one cow is expected to smile.